# Pointer invoke method pitfall?

Tags: go, 2-3-4-tree

I am writing a implementation about 2-3-4 tree. node structure is as below

```
type Node struct {
    items  []int
    childs []*Node
    parent *Node
}
```

I am confusing about the code below. In my opinon, the two part is doing the same thing. However,
one of these is wrong.

- right code

```
cur = cur.parent
cur._insertNode(upTo, rn)
upTo, rn = cur._splitNode()
```

- wrong code

```
cur.parent._insertNode(upTo, rn)
upTo, rn = cur.parent._splitNode()
cur = cur.parent
```

Can anyone tells me what is the difference?

What I expect is explaintion about the question.
Is it a Go pointer method pitfall?
Or compiler bug?

Comment: "Is it a golang pointer method pitfall? Or compiler bug?" Ask yourself: How likely is it that your toy code discovers an unknown compiler bug nobody else in the world ran into already?

Comment: "Or compiler bug?" -- It's never a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let *C* be the node that `cur` originally points to, let *A* be the node that is originally the parent of *C*, and suppose that the call to `_insertNode` inserts a new node *B* between *A* and *C*; so, we go from this:

```
A
|
C
```

(plus other nodes, not relevant to my point) to this:

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

(plus other nodes, still not relevant to my point).

The important thing to note is that before the call to `_insertNode`, the parent of *C* is *A*; and after the call to `_insertNode`, the parent of *C* is *B*.

With that in mind, here's your "right code", plus comments explaining what it's doing:

```
// initially, cur = C

// set cur = A:
cur = cur.parent

// insert B between A and C:
cur._insertNode(upTo, rn)

// cur is still A

// split A:
upTo, rn = cur._splitNode()
```

And here's your "wrong code", plus comments explaining what it's doing:

```
// initially, cur = C

// insert B between A and C:
cur.parent._insertNode(upTo, rn)

// cur.parent is now B

// split B:
upTo, rn = cur.parent._splitNode()

// set cur = B:
cur = cur.parent
```

Do you see?

Comment: Tl;DR: This isn't a Go pointer pitfall or a compiler bug. It's about the order of operations and ensuring you're working on the expected instance of the struct